# Infinite tangent line and rate of change.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

We know that if the tangent line exists then the derivative exists except for vertical tangent lines. For example $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{3}$ has no derivative at $x=0$.

How can we substantiate it both algebracially and intuitively? How about the rate of change or "speed" of the function at this point? The function is continuous and we visually we see that it is growing,but still does it mean the rate of change at $x=0$ is not defined?

Comment: Tangent line is straight continuing curve with the same slope as curve has in tangent point. Slope of curve $y=f(x)$ is derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, I know. I think this is not answer of my question.

Comment: Have you tried showing that $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = \infty$?

Comment: Rate of change at $x=0$ is infinite. That is not fully the same as not defined. Basic $(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=A$ requires $A$ to be finite, but there is extension of definition on case $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, Ok. If $f(t)= t^\frac{1}{3}$ is represent position of object respect to time what is the instantenous speed of this object at $t=0$ ? and how we could explain it intuitively?

Comment: It has infinite instantaneous speed at $t=0$. That is for every speed $v_1$ we can choose time interval $(0;t_1)$ with $t_1(v_1)$ such that average velocity in this interval is greater than $v_1$. Of course infinite speed is impossible from physical point of view, but here we consider situation in assumption that it is possible.

Comment: Average speed in $(0;t_1)$ is $\langle v\rangle =\frac{f(t_1)-f(0)}{t_1-0}$. For $f(t)=t^{\frac13}$, $\langle v \rangle=\frac{t_1^{\frac13}}{t_1}=t_1^{-\frac23}$. If $t_1=0.001$, $\langle v \rangle = 100$, if $t_1=0.000001$, $\langle v \rangle = 10000$ and so on.